# AbsoluteUrl in WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net

In my aspx page, the serverside web form generates a script tag to webresource.axd which looks like

```
<script src="/www/WebResource.axd?d=..." type="text/javascript">
```

I need the src of this auto generated script tag to have full qualified domain name instead of a relative url. something like the following.

```
<script src="http://www.mysite.com/WebResource.axd?d=..." type="text/javascript">
```

How can I achieve this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/WebResource.axd?d=...")%>' type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: the script tag is autogenerated by asp.net webform. I have no contorl over it since it.